# Total Items In Shipment PDF

Tags: orders, shipping, pdf, totals

I am trying to get the total number of items in an order and display them in the shipment PDF.

I am using the below code but I doubles the amount of items. For example, if there is 1 item it gets displayed as 2

```
<?php $order = $this->getPdfHelper()->getOrder();
    if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
        $invIncrementIDs = array();
        $invItems = array();
        $total = -0;
        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
            $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
            foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $invItems[] = $item->getQty();
                $total = $total + ($item->getQty());
            }
        }
    }
?>


<br/>
<h3>
    <strong><?php echo $this->__("Number of items:") ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $total; ?></strong>
</h3>
```

I'm not sure why but I'm thinking its to do with:

```
 $total = $total + ($item->getQty());
```

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $order = $this->getPdfHelper()->getOrder();
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $qty = $item->getQtyShipped();
        $total = $total + $qty;
    }
?>
```

`getQtyShipped();` Is the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

do you try this with configurable products? Then you count the configurable and the simple

Comment: I think you are right, its counting simple + configurable. I've tried `getAllVisibleItems` but its a non-object

Comment: getAllVisibleItems only exists on orders, not on invoices. I don'T see a way atm, to check whether an item is a child item. But what you can do is get the order and use getAllVisibleItems on the order.

Comment: Yes but `getAllVisibleItems` returns an empty `Array`

Comment: I think it is an answer. What he describes happens, when he counts simple an configurable items, case solved.